# Create exception accessible from both Model and Controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller

I simply want to create a custom exception that I can use as part of a fail from either a model or a controller. Is the lib directory the correct place for this, or are helpers / concerns useful for this.

If it is the lib directory what do I need to import and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the exception class to your *app/models* folder. Anything that's business logic for your application should be in the *app/models* folder (as [this article](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/02/14/love-your-lib-directory.html) talks about in more detail). The *lib* folder is where you put code that is basically external to your app (almost like the last step before you extract it into a gem some day).

Here is an example exception that you can refer to from anywhere in your app:

```
# app/models/my_exception.rb
class MyException < RuntimeError
end
```

And since the *app/models* folder is already autoloaded you're all set -- no need to require the file in an initializer or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks, will try that out when I get the chance!

Comment: Hey this isn't working for me... I'll change the question above to reflect that

Comment: @Imran I see you accepted it, did it start working now?